# How can I make the same dismissible shown in gif?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to make the same dismissible with animation in flutter.Here I share gif image of what I want.[image]

How can I make it? I can not find any package on pub dev.

I used swipeable_tile package ,but with it I could not get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that is developed based on the UI provided.

packages used :

```
flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
```

Check the sample code, i have created with the basic ui modify based on your requirement.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dismissible item'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 120,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                child: SizedBox.shrink()),
            Positioned(
              top: 16,
              child: Slidable(
                // Specify a key if the Slidable is dismissible.
                key: const ValueKey(0),

                // The end action pane is the one at the right or the bottom side.
                endActionPane: ActionPane(
                  motion: ScrollMotion(),
                  children: [
                    SlidableAction(
                      onPressed: (context) {},
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icons.delete,
                      label: 'Delete',
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 100,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('Text 1'),
                          Text('Text 2'),
                          Text('Text 3'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text('Third Item'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but I need animation effect.When we slide back it should wait for 2 seconds and show red container as it shown on gif